# actionscript-3 fullscreen flash projector

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, projector

is it possible to make fluid layout (fullscreen limited stage) for a win projector
but if we click the fullscreen button, the stage will fill the entire screen, how? need helps!!!

I've tried

```
fscommand("fullscreen", "true");
fscommand("allowscale", "false");
```

but the result not good

look the picture on my same question at 
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=1148246#post1148246

Answer (score 1):

Add these settings by default:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

And this for your fullscreen action:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to use this code on the first frame

```
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
play ();
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```